# Set sprite of Image to default None

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a project where I have an image on the screen that starts blank and then an image gets placed as the sprite. I was wonder how to make the sprite to return to being None like it is by default.
Thanks

Comment: `image = null` did it helped? o.O

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply set it to null to make it blank again.

If Image:

```
public Image  image;
image.sprite = null;
```

If RawImage:

```
public RawImage  image;
image.texture = null;
```